# How can the effect of a proposed edit be viewed?

Tags: support, mathjax, suggested-edits, review

I was sent a proposed edit of a question to check. The editor had done much work writing up several lines of LaTeX code, and it looked good. But I couldn't approve it without checking it carefully; and it is difficult to spot mistakes in extensive LaTeX code without seeing the MathJax rendition. How can I view the MathJax-rendered text?

Comment: You could click on improve to view the rendered text and then return back. However, this might cause failing a [meta-tag:review-audit] IIRC. I think something like this has been discussed on meta before, I was only able to find this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/preview-of-a-proposed-edit